# magento 2 enable swatches for out of stock products?

Tags: magento2, swatches, color-swatches

My Configurable product have some simple product which are out of stock when a swatch is clicked some swatches got disabled i just want to disable the swatch if pair does not exist i want to show the show if product is out of stock and swatch is enable not disabled